# C# отсчет времени по таймеру

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.
Нужно посылать запросы на Web сервис по временному регламенту.

1. 1 раз в 40 сек
2. 1 раз в 2 мин
3. один раз в сутки в 10:00:00
4. один раз в сутки в 20:00:00
5. один раз в сутки в 22:00:00

Код:

```
  private const double PeriodTimer = 10000;
    private DateTime _secondLevel40 = DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime _minutLevel2 = DateTime.Now;
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    //запуск таймера
    _timer = new Timer(PeriodTimer);
    _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

 private async void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

            //ВРЕМЕННОЙ УРОВЕНЬ 40сек
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_secondLevel40).Seconds >= 40)
            {
                _secondLevel40= DateTime.Now;
                //отправка диагностики
            }


            //ВРЕМЕННОЙ УРОВЕНЬ 2мин
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_minutLevel2).Minutes >= 2)
            {
                _minutLevel2 = DateTime.Now;
                //считываем инфо.
            }



            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 10 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0 && DateTime.Now.Second <= 10)
            {
                //считываем нормативное расписание.
            }


            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 20 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0 && DateTime.Now.Second <= 10)
            {
                //считываем нормативное расписание.
            }



            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 22 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0 && DateTime.Now.Second <= 10)
            {
                 //считываем нормативное расписание.
            }
    }
```

Т.е. таймер срабатывает раз в 10 сек и проверяет время.
Циклические интервалы (раз в 40 сек) думаю нормально отработают со временем. А  сработка в конкретное время боюсь может не произойти из за неточного счета самого таймера.
Подскажите как лучше сделать?

Comment: Как вариант можно создать отдельный поток, в котором будет 'бесконечный' `while` который будет расчитывать время до следующей операции изходя из параметров (находить timespan) и засыпать до этого момента `thread.sleep(delay)`.`while(work){ calculateDelay(); thread.sleep(delay); doSomeWork();}`

Comment: А как в общем случае генерировать событие при наступлении определенного часа? Неужели никто не сталкивался

Comment: Уже написал механизм как это можно сделать.
Как пример этот [ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445741/thread-sleep-wait-until-a-new-day)

Comment: Думал все не так))

Comment: По моему коду могут быть проблемы сработок?

Comment: 1. Лучше создать 5 различных таймеров для различных событий и гарантировать, что каждый обработчик будет вызван, в случае если предыдущий выдаст исключение. 2. Используйте свойство TimeSpan.TotalSeconds вместо TimeSpan.Seconds.

Comment: Лучше не велосипедить велосипед, а взять нормальную библиотеку, например https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet

Comment: Спасибо воспользуюсь кварцем))